# Change color on single-series line chart using rCharts and Highcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

Is it possible to change the color of a line using rCharts and Highcharts so that the line color changes depending on a factor? I've done this with ggplot2 but would like to make an interactive version if possible. I've tried

```
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type="line")
h1$series(data=mydf$myvalue, name="", groups = c("myfactor"))
h1$xAxis(tickInterval = 4, categories = mydf$myXaxis)
```

but that's not working, line stays the same color. Sample data

```
myvalue <- c(16, 18, 5, 14, 10)
myXaxis <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
myfactor <- c("old", "old", "old", "new", "new")
mydf <- data.frame(myvalue, myXaxis, myfactor)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I received a great suggestion on Twitter from @kyle_e_walker to use Dimple with rCharts instead of Highcharts http://bl.ocks.org/walkerke/ae98fc103dd9b9dcce0f